# Subquery for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I need assistance in joining the two query statements together using subquery.  I am confused on how I can combine the two together. I appreciate the help.

```
SELECT * FROM MEDICAL_PROCEDURE
JOIN PROCEDURE_CATEGORY ON medical_procedure.procedure_category_id = PROCEDURE_CATEGORY.PROCEDURE_CATEGORY_ID;

SELECT 
      Medical_procedure.medical_procedure_id,
      COUNT(procedure_tool_supply.medical_procedure_id) AS Supply_Needed
FROM Procedure_tool_supply
JOIN Medical_Procedure on Procedure_tool_supply.medical_procedure_id = Medical_procedure.medical_procedure_id
GROUP BY Procedure_tool_supply.medical_procedure_id
HAVING COUNT(Procedure_tool_supply.medical_procedure_id) < 3;
```

Comment: can you please share ur table structure? n elaborate how u want result ?

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql-server? Those are two very different database engines.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really test without test data, but this should work. Hopefully I figured out correctly what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  MEDICAL_PROCEDURE P
  JOIN PROCEDURE_CATEGORY C ON 
    P.procedure_category_id = C.PROCEDURE_CATEGORY_ID
  cross apply (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(T.medical_procedure_id) AS Supply_Needed
    FROM 
      Procedure_tool_supply T
    where 
      T.medical_procedure_id = P.medical_procedure_id
    GROUP BY 
      T.medical_procedure_id
    HAVING 
      COUNT(T.medical_procedure_id) < 3
  ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.  But if your intent is to include the derived `Supply_Needed` column from the second query on each row from the first query, and to restrict the rows returned to those that have a `medical_procedure_id` value returned by the second query, then...

you could do something like this:

```
SELECT mp.*
     , pc.*
     , ct.Supply_Needed
  FROM MEDICAL_PROCEDURE mp
  JOIN PROCEDURE_CATEGORY pc
    ON mp.procedure_category_id = pc.PROCEDURE_CATEGORY_ID
  JOIN ( SELECT pr.medical_procedure_id
              , COUNT(ts.medical_procedure_id) AS Supply_Needed
           FROM Procedure_tool_supply ts
           JOIN Medical_Procedure pr
             ON ts.medical_procedure_id = pr.medical_procedure_id
          GROUP BY ts.medical_procedure_id
         HAVING COUNT(ts.medical_procedure_id) < 3
       ) ct
    ON ct.medical_procedure_id = mp.medical_procedure_id
```